# What's is the equivalent of down-pane command in tmux 1.4

Tags: tmux

In tmux 1.2, I have a configure line in tmux.conf

```
bind -n C-o down-pane
```

so that remote user can press Ctrl+O to switch between panes.

But in tmux 1.4, down-pane is no longer valid. What's the alternative to down-pane?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select-pane -D
```

More info from the first hit on Google for "`tmux down-pane`": http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/729

Comment: Good answer and great link. I tried it. ``bind -n C-o select-pane -t :.+"`` work as a charm.

Comment: Just FYI, 'o' is bound to that command by default (<prefix> o moves  the focus to the next pane). The default binding for C-o is to rotate the panes themselves, bringing the next pane to the focus, as it were.